# Fixing the scaling for a `div` tag

Tags: html, css, scaling

I am creating a simple site that consists of a header, navbar, and content. It almost runs fine in a browser with a screen resolution size of 1366 X 768, but if you resize the browser, all kinds of things mess up. The title gets large, and goes over everything. The navbar and title bar get tiny so I can not hover over the links. If the browser size is small, hovering over the links will overflow. In any resolution or size, the navbar is extended beyond the screen size. How can I fix these issues so that my site will scale correctly. I am not the best designer, and am more familiar backend web development. I am using measurements like like `vh` and `vw` or `%` to size my components.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/James_Parsons/nfya71cr/embedded/result/)

*HTML*

```
<header id="header"><h1 class="title">Test Test Test</h1></header>
    <nav id="nav">
        <p class="text">Test</p>
        <p class="text">Test</p>
        <p class="text">Test</p>
        <p class="text">Test</p>
        <p class="text">Test</p>
    </nav>
```

*CSS*

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand);

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #dddddd;  
}

#header {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    background-color: #9000f0;
    height: 20vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: none;
}

#nav {
    background-color: #44aa66;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    text-align:  center;
}

.title {
    color: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.text {
    height: 65%;
    width: 5%;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.text:hover {
    background-color: #44cc66;
}
```

Comment: Put your code in your question please.

Comment: looks fine for me in chrome, even with resizing from 400px to 1920px, i do suggest tho to use `.text { height: 40px; }` //anything but percent

Comment: @j08691 sorry, I felt it a bit redundant to paste code and link to a fiddle, also, how is this off topic?

Comment: @DomlThe-Bread wont using `px` make it unscalable. Other types such as `vh` and `vw` seem to act buggy. I have not tested it in chrome, but it sucks in IE.

Comment: It *was* off-topic because there was no code in the question asking about code.

Comment: @DomlThe-Bread I see wht you mean. it works fine *in* the fiddle, but not in a browser opened manually.

Comment: @James_Parsons which version of IE are you using? IE has always had problems with VH and VW -> http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your mark up it is limited only for your resolution i.e. 1366 X 768
You are using extra padding without using border-box property
and height should not be used if you are bothered about resizing of the browser, use min-height property instead if you want to provide a height to the element.

have a look at below jsfiddle link and you will have a clear idea about this.

for example border box property

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RockRathore/vew83g1x/1/

Answer (score 0):

VH and VW are sometimes buggy and not correctly working if you are using IE.

so my suggestion is to "cheat" the vh values by using

```
#header {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand);

body {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #dddddd; 
}

#header {
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-left: 35px;
 background-color: #9000f0;
 height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: none;
}

#nav {
 background-color: #44aa66;
 height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 10%;
 text-align:  center;
}

.title {
 color: #f9f9f9;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 48px;
}

.text {
 height: 0;
 width: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 7.5%;
 color: #f9f9f9;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 float: left;
}

.text:hover {
 background-color: #44cc66;
}
```

```html
<header id="header"><h1 class="title">Test Test Test</h1></header>
 <nav id="nav">
  <p class="text">Test</p>
  <p class="text">Test</p>
  <p class="text">Test</p>
  <p class="text">Test</p>
  <p class="text">Test</p>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a jumping off point... but this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/s5u4xg2s/48/) shows examples of using vmax and media queries for your goals.  You can experiment with the values for your purposes.

Code:

```
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
#header {
    padding: 2vmax 2vmax;
    background-color: #9000f0;
    height: 9vmax;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: none;
}
#nav {
    background-color: #44aa66;
    min-height: 4vmax;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 2vmax;
}
.title {
    color: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 0;
    font-family:'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 5vw;
}
.text {
    color: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 0;
    float:left;
    padding: .6vmax 1.5vmax;
    font-size: 2.3vmax;
}
.text:hover {
    background-color: #44cc66;
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    .text {
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    #nav {
        height: 25px;
    }
}
```